# Express server not working on reverse proxy (NGINX)

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am testing my express server running on proxy. My nginx config file for in sites-available is:

```
server {


server_name open.yousico.com;

  gzip on;
  gzip_proxied any;
  gzip_types application/javascript application/x-javascript text/css text/javascript;
  gzip_comp_level 6;
  gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  gzip_min_length 256;

  location /_next/static/ {
      alias /var/www/yousi-website/.next/static/;
      expires 365d;
      access_log off;
    }

  location / {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

  location /api {
      rewrite ^/codify(.*) $1 break;
      proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:3001";
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/open.yousico.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/open.yousico.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
 server {
    if ($host = open.yousico.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


  listen 80;
  server_name open.yousico.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

My server file for my express server listening on 3001 is:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.listen(3001, console.log("server is running on 3001"));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('API is running');
});

app.get('/hello', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World');
});
```

I tested this express server on my local machine, and it seems to be working fine, but when I deploy it to my cloud server, it displays "Cannot GET /api", is there something wrong with my config file? My understanding is that I set my location to /api and direct it to port 3001, and I'm sure that the server is running on 3001.
[image: Cannot GET in the browser]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Cannot XXX /YYY" is the Express default response when there is no handler for method XXX for path YYY.

In your case, I don't see an `app.get("/api", ...)` handler in your server code, so the error is quite warranted.

The rewrite statement in your nginx config,

```
rewrite ^/codify(.*) $1 break;
```

doesn't make sense either since there's no way for `location /api` to match `/codify`.

If you meant to strip the `/api` out before the URL is passed to your Express server,

```
rewrite ^/api(.*) $1 break;
```

in which case `/api` would be passed as `/`, and that would match your `app.get("/")`...